# Need to change pace of one of the axes in my chart matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, charts, multiple-axes

Fairly new to plotting need help
have this [DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1A4d.png) that I'm working on. trying to change the pace on my left y_axis to be 5 instead of 10 but I guess 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'yticks' so I can't use

```
ax.yticks(np.arange(0, max(GDP['GDP'])+5, 5))
```

This is my Code ( the plotting part)

```
fig = plt.figure() # Create matplotlib figure

ax = fig.add_subplot(111) # Create matplotlib axes
ax2 = ax.twinx() # Create another axes that shares the same x-axis as ax.

width = 0.7
newdf.GDP.plot(kind='bar', color='#8D99FB', ax=ax, width=width)
newdf.Unemployment.plot(kind='line', color='red', ax=ax2)

ax.set_ylabel('GDP over The years in billions of dollars')
#ax.yticks(np.arange(0, max(GDP['GDP'])+5, 5))
ax2.set_ylabel('Percentage of Unemployment/total Population')
ax.set_xticklabels(newdf.Year.tolist())

ax.set_xlim(-width,len(newdf.Year.tolist()))

plt.title('GDP over The years in billions of dollars')



'''
ax.yticks(np.arange(0, max(GDP['GDP'])+5, 5))

'''
plt.show()
```

Thanks

Comment: Please add the actual data instead of a screenshot

Comment: `ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0, max(GDP['GDP'])+5, 5))` and I'd like you to give your attention to the `set_` part…

Comment: You can use `from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator` and `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(5))` to get ticks at every multiple of 5 without the need to calculate the maximum.